Parse CSV in Svelte with papaparse
I'm trying to parse a local csv in svelte but the logged object has nothing to do with the parsed file. The file is in the /src/db-csv/folder.
+layout.server.js
import Papa from 'papaparse'

export const load = async ({ params, fetch }) => {

  const result = await fetch("http://localhost:5173/db-csv/customers.dat", {
    headers: { "content-type": "text/csv;charset=UTF-8" },
  });

  const fileContent = await result.text();

  let parsedCsvCstomers = Papa.parse(fileContent, {header: true})

  return {
    customers: parsedCsvCstomers.data
  };
};

Also the csv has 8000 rows, the array has less objects and It looks like it's reading the svelte page.


You cannot just fetch data from an arbitrary directory. You also should never have localhost:5173 anywhere, that's the dev server.
You probably should import the file, presumably with ?raw query to get the contents.

the Papaparse docs says that it's possible to parse a local file. The url I've put it's just for testing.

You cannot fetch it, the server will not serve it.
